# How to disable button after one click in React.js

Tags: reactjs, button, disable

I want to disable button after one click.
I use this code:

```
const handleClick = (event) => {
    event.currentTarget.disabled = true;
    console.log(event);
    console.log('button clicked');
  };
```

When I have only one button it Works.

```
<div className="col-md-1">
          <button type="submit" onClick={handleClick} className="btn btn- 
                success">Filtriraj</button>
        </div>
```

but when I have multiple same buttons it doesn't work.

```
<div className="showAds" >
        {adsList.map((val, key) => {
          return <div className="ad" key={key}>
            <h4> {val.content}</h4>
            <h5><a href=""><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="#bb2d3b" className="bi bi-geo-alt-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path d="M8 16s6-5.686 6-10A6 6 0 0 0 2 6c0 4.314 6 10 6 10zm0-7a3 3 0 1 1 0-6 3 3 0 0 1 0 6z"></path>
            </svg>{val.adress}</a></h5>
            <h5>Likes: {val.likes}</h5>
            <div>
              {""}
              <button type="submit" onClick={() => {addLike(val.id, val.likes + 1);handleClick}} className="btn btn-success" > LIKE</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        })}
      </div>
```

The problem is when I try to call handleClick it shows me the error:

```
 Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
```

Comment: Replace `() => {addLike(val.id, val.likes + 1);handleClick}` with `(e) => {addLike(val.id, val.likes + 1);handleClick(e)}`

Comment: Will post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click handler you have

```
() => {addLike(val.id, val.likes + 1);handleClick}
```

This ignores the event argument, also it incorrectly calls the `handleClick`. A correct version would be

```
(e) => {addLike(val.id, val.likes + 1);handleClick(e)}
```

This takes the argument of the event (`e`) and passes it to `handleClick`.

Answer (score 1):

```
export default function App() {
  let [adsList, setAdsList] = React.useState([
    { key: 0, id: 0, content: 'NewYork', adress: 'NewYork', likes: 0 },
    { key: 1, id: 1, content: 'Vancouver', adress: 'Vancouver', likes: 0 },
    { key: 2, id: 2, content: 'Toronto', adress: 'Toronto', likes: 0 },
  ]);

  const addLike = (id) => {
    let newAdsList = [...adsList];
    newAdsList[id].likes++;
    setAdsList(newAdsList);
  };

  return (
    <div className="showAds">
      {adsList.map((val, key) => {
        return (
          <div className="ad" key={key}>
            <h4> {val.content}</h4>
            <h5>
              <a href="">
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  width="16"
                  height="16"
                  fill="#bb2d3b"
                  className="bi bi-geo-alt-fill"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                >
                  <path d="M8 16s6-5.686 6-10A6 6 0 0 0 2 6c0 4.314 6 10 6 10zm0-7a3 3 0 1 1 0-6 3 3 0 0 1 0 6z"></path>
                </svg>
                {val.adress}
              </a>
            </h5>
            <h5>Likes: {val.likes}</h5>
            <div>
              {''}
              <button
                type="submit"
                onClick={() => {
                  addLike(val.id);
                  event.target.disabled = true;
                }}
                className="btn btn-success"
              >
                LIKE
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

this should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can disable a button in React.js by setting the disabled attribute to true on the button element. In your code, you've created a handleClick function that sets event.currentTarget.disabled = true when called. To disable the button after one click, you can call this handleClick function as the onClick event for the button.

In your code you are using it correctly in the first button, but for the second button you are calling it in an arrow function and you don't need to wrap it in an arrow function, you can just call it like this:

```html
<button type="submit" onClick={() => {addLike(val.id, val.likes + 1);handleClick()}} className="btn btn-success" > LIKE</button>
```